# How to return HTTP 403 after successful authentication, but unsuccessful authorization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application which also uses Spring Security. I want to check if user has access to login to the application, but it must be after authentication. The point is that, at login, the user selects the project to which they must connect. A user can be allowed to connect to one project, but can not be allowed to connect to another project. However, if user enters invalid credentials, message about invalid credentials must be shown first even if user has no right to login to the selected project. For this reason, checking for the rights to the project must be after authentication.

This my SecurityConfig class:

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram.config;

import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.CurrentUser;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.PermissionAliasConstants;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/lib/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().successHandler(successHandler()).loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return (request, response, e) -> {
            logger.debug("Returning HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN with message: \"{}\"", e.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), e.getMessage());
        };
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                CurrentUser user = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
                if (!user.hasAccessRight(PermissionAliasConstants.LOGIN)) {
                    throw new AccessDeniedException(String.format("User \"%s\" is not authorized to login \"%s\" project", user.getUsername(), user.getProject().getName()));
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram.serviceimpl;

import org.aze.accountingprogram.common.Constants;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.exceptions.DataNotFoundException;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.AccessRightsPermission;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.CurrentUser;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.Project;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.models.User;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.service.AccessRightsService;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.service.ProjectService;
import org.aze.accountingprogram.service.UserService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessRightsService accessRightsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user;
        Project project;
        final String projectId = request.getParameter(Constants.SESSION_PROJECT_ID);
        logger.debug("Username: {}, projectId: {}", username, projectId);

        try {
            user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        // Value of projectId is from combo box which is filled from table of projects
        // That is why there is no probability that the project will not be found
        project = projectService.getProjectById(Integer.valueOf(projectId));

        // User can have different rights for different projects
        List<AccessRightsPermission> accessRights = accessRightsService.getAccessRightsByProject(user.getId(), project.getId());
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>(accessRights.size());
        authorities.addAll(accessRights.stream().map(right -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(right.getAlias())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        final CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser(user, project, authorities);

        // If to check LOGIN access right to project here, and user entered right credentials
        // then user will see message about invalid credentials.
        // .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()) at SecurityConfig is not working in this case
//        if (!currentUser.hasAccessRight(PermissionAliasConstants.LOGIN)) {
//            throw new AccessDeniedException(String.format("User \"%s\" is not authorized to login \"%s\" project", user.getUsername(), project.getName()));
//        }

        logger.info("Logged in user: {}", currentUser);
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

and LoginController

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
    }

}
```

`successHandler()` works and application throws `AccessDeniedException` if user has not access right to login to the project. But `accessDeniedHandler()` doesn't work and doesn't send HTTP 403. Instead I receive HTTP 500.

How to return response with HTTP 403 and message of exception (e.g. "User "tural" is not authorized to login "AZB" project") and to handle it in `LoginController` (using `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)` or `@ExceptionHandler`)?

Comment: Don't check permissions in the successhandler. Instead write a security expression which validates if the user can access the project. Your userservice shouldn't depend on a request/session variable. It should only obtain the user with its rights. You should wrote a security expression limiting him to access things he isn't allowed to. You are basically working around Spring Securiyt instead of working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can inject the `HttpServletResponse` in the login POST method of your Controller.

Therefore, if your service notifies you that authorization is not OK, you can for example do

response.setStatus(403);

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginAction(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String pw, HttpServletResponse response) {
   doStuff(login,pw);
   if(service.isNotHappy(login,pw)){
      response.setStatus(403);
   }else{
      // happy flow
   }
   ...
}
```

**// UPDATE :**

since the

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

method is the implementation of the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` interface, indeed you can't inject the `HttpServletResponse` like you would in a `@RequestMapping` annotated controller.

However, here is another (hopefully correct!) solution :

1) In the implementation of the `loadUserByUsername(String x)` method, if the user does not have the access rights, throw a `CustomYourException`

2) Create a new `ExceptionHandlingController` class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` at `class level` (and make sure it gets scanned like your controllers) that contains a method like this :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

   @ExceptionHandler({CustomYourException.class})
   public ModelAndView handleCustomExceptionError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, CustomYourException cyee) {
       // this method will be triggered upon CustomYourException only
       // you can manipulate the response code here, 
       // return a custom view, use a special logger
       // or do whatever else you want here :)
   }
}
```

As you can see, this handler will be called based on what specific exceptions you define in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation - very useful ! 
From there, you can manipulate the HttpServletResponse and set the response code you want, and/or send the user to a specific view.

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: I have not handler of @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST). Spring Security handles POST request to /login itself. I configured authentication similar to example from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: Updated the answer with a new solution, please check it out :)

Comment: I tried this solution before writing this question. `loadUserByUsername` runs before checking password. So, in this case, if user hasn't access to project and entered invalid username or password then application will say that, user has not access to project instead, but it should say that, user entered invalid credentials. It means that, authorization will appear before authentication.

Comment: This may cause a problem when two users have similar usernames but different rights projects. If one user makes a mistake and accidentally enters another similar username (existing in database), which does not have the rights to the project, the application will confuse him saying that he has no rights to the project, rather than to say that he has entered the wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are supposed to *return;* after *response.sendError()*